# Word and FILLIN

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing, macros

I have a lot old WORD files, ie .doc-files, that I want to print to pdf. The problem is that many of the files contains one or more FILLIN (macro?), so when the printing starts I need to click OK in every dialog. Not very practical for thousands of documents!

Printing from the commandline with, currently, the options: /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit

Any tips on how to suppress these dialogs/macros? Is there maybe a more suitable/better macro than FilePrintDefault?

Maybe there is a way to say OK automatically?

Comment: Try to use `/x` command line switch (it must supress all dialogs assuming Yes).

Comment: Sorry, tried that but the same FILLIN-dialogs keep popping up!

Comment: Did you untick the Word option to "Update fields before printing"?  (In Word Options | Display | Printing options)

Comment: Yes, this option not enabled.